# Getting top two post_ids from votes table

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a votes table that has a `post_id` column, a `user_id` column, and a `vote` column. When someone votes for a post, a row is added that records the id of the post they voted for, their `user_id`, and the `vote` column is set to the value of 1. I can find the post with the most votes by executing this query:

```
$toppostid = Vote::orderBy(DB::raw('sum(\'vote\')'))
            ->groupBy('post_id')
            ->find(1)
            ->pluck('post_id');
```

Now it seems obvious that I could find the second post by setting the `find` method to "2". However, when I do that, it returns the same `post_id` as the original function. So, given this table, how would I find the top two posts and return them?

Comment: You need `take(2)` instead of `find` and `lists('post_id')` instead of `pluck` to get an array. `pluck` returns single, first value

Answer (score 1):

`find()` is actually finding the row with that ID, not finding one row as you seem to be assuming. What you need is the `take()` operator, which acts as a limit.

Try:

```
$toppostid = Vote::orderBy(DB::raw('sum(\'vote\')'))
        ->groupBy('post_id')
        ->take(2)
        ->pluck('post_id');
```

See the [offset and limit section](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects).

EDIT: It's also unclear in the documentation whether `pluck()` will only take the first row's ID. You may need to exclude that to get your desired result.